# WordPress: moving multisites gives Error establishing database connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

After moving my Wordpress Multisites to new domain it gives error in database connection 
following is my config.php file

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
$base = '/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.vanijyabhawan.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

I've replace all possible value database. but no hopes

Thanks

Comment: Have you change the `db connection settings` after moving your site ?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your setup (did you just dump your DB and push it into the new server's database instance?), I'd say it likely is somewhere in your database. To check, you could grep your database dump:

```
cat your_db_file.sql | grep -i theolddomain.com
```

If you find indeed that there are references to your old domain, you can easily replace them like so:

```
find your_db_file.sql | xargs perl -pi -e "s/theolddomain.com/thenewdomain.com/g"
```

Multisite is VERY particular about it's domain entries, make sure to go back over all of your settings such as domain mappings, primary domain check, etc.

Comment: Make sure you're also properly defining `DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, and DB_HOST` in your `wp-config.php` What error exactly are you getting?

Comment: What I've Done is (1) export database from my old sites (2) find and replace all occurrence of domain name (3) after that changed my config.php file as per previous post ... here is screenshot https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2vh_84Wn5tDZjZ0UVM1d1FqZnc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: as mentioned this is multisite(network) installation so when I commented this code than i'm able to access my main site define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
$base = '/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.vanijyabhawan.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

Comment: yes i've changed all parameters ...and it works fine if comment   define('MULTISITE', true) ...but what i expect is multisite

Comment: Sorry, that's probably about as far as I can get without being able to really look at the code or DB dump. I'm not quite a WP MultiSite `ninja` or anything, but hopefully someone else here is - also, have you looked through the [WordPress SE?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is not answer as it does not work in my case too.